# Power BI report is not loading in MVC application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, powerbi, powerbi-embedded

Few days back i learnt making reports in power BI and it was great experience learning power BI. As i am creating a dashboard for my MVC based web application, i wanted to make look and fill of my dashboard attractive. I am thinking of embedding power BI report with that for that i have used following code inside view :-

```
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/PowerBI/powerbi.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function () {
        var iframe = document.getElementById("iFrameEmbedReport");
        iframe.src = "https://app.powerbi.com/reportEmbed?reportId=" + embedReportId;
        iframe.onload = postActionLoadReport;
    }

    function postActionLoadReport() {
        var m = {
            action: "loadReport",
            accessToken: accessToken
        };
        message = JSON.stringify(m);

        iframe = document.getElementById("iFrameEmbedReport");
        iframe.contentWindow.postMessage(message, "*");;
      }
    </script>
    <style>
        #iFrameEmbedReport {
            width: 95%;
            height: 95%;
        }
    </style>
    <iframe ID="iFrameEmbedReport"></iframe>
</body>
```

And code for controller is  given below :-

```
public class DashBoardController : Controller
    {
        string baseUri = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["PowerBiDataset"];
        string AccessToken = string.Empty;
        // GET: DashBoard
        public ActionResult DashBoard()
        {

            if (Request.Params.Get("code") != null)
            {
                Session["AccessToken"] = GetAccessToken(
                    Request.Params.GetValues("code")[0],
                    WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ClientID"],
                    WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ClientSecret"],
                    WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["RedirectUrl"]);


                Response.Redirect("~/DashBoard/DashBoard");
            }

            if (Session["AccessToken"] != null)
            {

                AccessToken = Session["AccessToken"].ToString();
                GetReport(0);
            }
            return View();
        }


        protected void GetReport(int index)
        {
            System.Net.WebRequest request = System.Net.WebRequest.Create(
                String.Format("{0}/Reports",
                baseUri)) as System.Net.HttpWebRequest;

            request.Method = "GET";
            request.ContentLength = 0;
            request.Headers.Add("Authorization", String.Format("Bearer {0}", AccessToken));

            using (var response = request.GetResponse() as System.Net.HttpWebResponse)
            {

                using (var reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
                {

                    PBIReports Reports = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<PBIReports>(reader.ReadToEnd());

                    if (Reports.value.Length > 0)
                    {
                        var report = Reports.value[index];
                        ViewData["AccessToken"] = Session["AccessToken"].ToString();
                        ViewData["EmbedURL"] = report.embedUrl;
                        ViewData["ReportID"] = report.id;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        public void GetAuthorizationCode()
        {

            var @params = new NameValueCollection
            {

                {"response_type", "code"},
                {"client_id", WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ClientID"]},
                {"resource", WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["PowerBiAPI"]},
                { "redirect_uri", WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["RedirectUrl"]}
            };

            var queryString = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(string.Empty);
            queryString.Add(@params);

            Response.Redirect(String.Format(WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AADAuthorityUri"] + "?{0}", queryString));


        }

        public string GetAccessToken(string authorizationCode, string clientID, string clientSecret, string redirectUri)
        {
            TokenCache TC = new TokenCache();

            string authority = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AADAuthorityUri"];
            AuthenticationContext AC = new AuthenticationContext(authority, TC);
            ClientCredential cc = new ClientCredential(clientID, clientSecret);

            return AC.AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCode(
                authorizationCode,
                new Uri(redirectUri), cc).AccessToken;
        }
    }
    public class PBIReports
    {
        public PBIReport[] value { get; set; }
    }
    public class PBIReport
    {
        public string id { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string webUrl { get; set; }
        public string embedUrl { get; set; }
    }
```

As i think, I am doing everything right but i don't know why it's not able to display report. Please suggest me if i did any mistake in the above given code.

Comment: What errors do you see?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear where the error is, as you provided lots of code and no specfics on the error itself. Here are few things to note:

- To embed Power BI content in your HTML you just need an empty `div` element
- Too much code overall.

You need to perform following steps:

- Acquire authentication token by using `AuthenticationContext.AcquireTokenAsync` with credentials provisioned on Power BI side
- Instantiate `PowerBIClient` with the token you just obtained. That's the token for your application. Never pass it to users. Don't store in Session as it'll expire. `PowerBIClient(new Uri(_Context.ApiUrl), new TokenCredentials(authResult.AccessToken, "Bearer"))`
- Obtain ID(s) of content that's available in Power BI. There are different APIs for different types (dashboards, reports, tiles) as well as for content that's in Groups(workspaces) or not, e.g. `client.Dashboards.GetDashboardsInGroupAsync(GroupId)`. This step could be skipped if you already know what type of content you're getting and its ID. Keep in mind that if `EmbedUrl` property is empty on returned object(s) you won't be able to render, even if you manually construct such url.
- Obtain **Embed Token** for particular content. There are different methods available, e.g. `client.Reports.GenerateTokenInGroupAsync(GroupId, Id-of-content, new GenerateTokenRequest(accessLevel: "view"))`
- The final step is to apply Embed Token and EmbedUrl on the client-side. Something among following lines:

.

```
var embedToken = $('#embedToken').val();
var txtEmbedUrl = $('#txtReportEmbed').val();
var txtEmbedReportId = $('#txtEmbedReportId').val();
var models = window['powerbi-client'].models;
var permissions = models.Permissions.All;

var config= {
    type: 'report',
    tokenType: models.TokenType.Embed,
    accessToken: embedToken,
    embedUrl: txtEmbedUrl,
    id: txtEmbedReportId,
    permissions: permissions,
    settings: {
        filterPaneEnabled: true,
        navContentPaneEnabled: true
    }
};

var embedContainer = $('#embedContainer')[0];
var report = powerbi.embed(embedContainer, config);
```

You should be able to test your stuff [here](https://microsoft.github.io/PowerBI-JavaScript/demo/v2-demo/index.html#). Just plugin your values.

You can also observe sample app here][2](https://github.com/Microsoft/PowerBI-Developer-Samples). Flow provided above is for "app owns data" case.